Spring Boot Database Configuration - Switch between different DBs at runtime
I have multiple databases that I want to connect to in my Springboot Application at runtime, how can I do that?
I have tried using context.xml and create a datasource switching configuration using the jndi names for the datasources, however I want to do the same with application.properties file and also while using Data JPA for tables.

have you tried googling before you asked? literall first result: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources

It doesn't work in my case as i also need to use context.xml for other things and this springboot project is part of a jsp servlet project and i am already switching between dbs using context.xml but now i am moving some parts of it to application.properties.

I use Maven profiles to apply a different configuration when running locally. That way is easy to swtich between databases. I'm not sure this is your use case, though.

Multi-tenancy might be what you're looking for. Have a look at this answer here.
On top of that, to pass the datasource properties from your application.properties file, you could do something like this:
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("application.datasource.my-datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties myDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

Then retrieve the properties like this in your code:
myDataSourceProperties().getUrl()
myDataSourceProperties().getUsername()
myDataSourceProperties().getPassword()
myDataSourceProperties().getDriverClassName()

and in your application.properties:
application.datasource.my-datasource.url=url
application.datasource.my-datasource.username=username
application.datasource.my-datasource.password=password
application.datasource.my-datasource.driver-class-name=driver

